# Any XPath/XSLT/XQuery 3.0 specific learning resources out there?

Tags: xquery, xpath-3.0, xslt-3.0

I'd prefer books. Do you know of any due to be released? Work ongoing?

I ask as I want to get up to speed with the new features in 3.0 (I know its not finalized yet), but I can't seem to find much. I know I could ref the ongoing spec but if that were enough for me I wouldn't be asking.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question - an XQuery 3.0 book would be great!

Comment: @John: Nor would an XSLT 3.0 book ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I use the [BaseX summary of XQuery 3.0 new features](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0) -- it's short, but covers the high points -- and refer to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/) for details not covered therein.

Comment: Ok, thanks, short of a nice book on the subject seems the best I can expect right now.

Comment: I added some infos about *higher-order functions* (http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Higher-Order_Functions), which are (in my opinion) the most exciting new possibility in *XQuery 3.0*. They definitely make XQuery a more useful functional language.